# BottomSheetDialogFragment AdjustResize SoftInput not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-softkeyboard, bottom-sheet

Hei I am currently trying to create a BottomSheetDialogFragment with the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <com.indico.recorder.views.DonkeyConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/album_edit_info_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorBackgroundTinted"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipChildren="true"
        android:clipToPadding="true">
        <View
            android:id="@+id/album_edit_draggable_indicator"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:alpha="0.65"
            android:background="@drawable/draggable_indicator"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/album_edit_title_container"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:elevation="1dp"/>
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/album_edit_title_container"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/album_edit_draggable_indicator"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/album_edit_description_container"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
            <com.indico.recorder.views.AutoClearEditText
                android:id="@+id/album_edit_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLength="@integer/media_title_max_length"
                android:hint="@string/session_name_hint"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/album_edit_description_container"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/albumEditDivider"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/album_edit_title_container"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/album_edit_description"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="75dp"
                android:textAlignment="textStart"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine|textAutoCorrect|textCapSentences"
                android:maxLines="@integer/media_description_max_length"
                android:hint="@string/session_description_hint"
                android:gravity="start|top"
                android:visibility="visible"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        <View
            android:id="@+id/albumEditDivider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.2dp"
            android:alpha="0.75"
            android:background="@drawable/divider_horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/album_edit_description_container"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
    </com.indico.recorder.views.DonkeyConstraintLayout>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/album_edit_activate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/capture_selection_item_background">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/album_edit_activate_icon"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_check_white_24dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/album_edit_activate_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:text="@string/album_edit_activate"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textColor="@color/colorOnSurface"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/album_edit_activate_icon"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The purpose here is to make the appearing softinput adjustresize and anchor below the whole layout instead of panning to the edttextfields. Based on a lot of research on how to get this to work with `fitSystemWindows` and other window attributes lead to the following style for all my bottom sheets:

```
<style name="BottomSheet.Theme" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/BottomSheet.Style</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:label">@null</item>
        <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustPan|stateVisible</item>
        <item name="android:windowClipToOutline">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="BottomSheet.Style" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
        <item name="behavior_peekHeight">300dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/squared_card_background</item>
        <item name="behavior_hideable">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustPan|stateVisible</item>
    </style>
```

I have not specified `windowSoftInputMode` in the manifest as the default behaviour is desired for the rest of the applciaiton.

The Bottom Sheet fragment:

```
class AlbumCreateSheet: BottomSheetDialogFragment(), View.OnClickListener {

    companion object {
        private val tag = AlbumCreateSheet::class.java.simpleName
        fun show(fragmentManager: FragmentManager) {
            return AlbumCreateSheet().show(fragmentManager, tag)
        }
    }

    private lateinit var titleView: EditText
    private lateinit var descriptionView: EditText

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        dialog.window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.sheet_album_create, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        titleView = view.findViewById(R.id.album_create_title)
        descriptionView = view.findViewById(R.id.album_create_description)

        view.findViewById<View>(R.id.album_create_create).setOnClickListener(this)

    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        when(v?.id) {
            R.id.album_create_create -> {
                useDefaultRealm {
                    executeTransaction {
                        val session = Session(name = titleView.text.toString(),
                                description = descriptionView.text.toString())
                        it.insertOrUpdate(session)
                    }
                }
                dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any tips on how to solve this, and make the softinput adjustresize the bottomseheet at whole are much welcome :)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: No i did not :(

Comment: Late to the party, but this line has to be removed from style: `<item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustPan|stateVisible</item>`

Answer (score -1):

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
val dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)

dialog.window?.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)
dialog.setOnShowListener {
    Handler().post {
        val bottomSheet = (dialog as? BottomSheetDialog)?.findViewById<View>(R.id.design_bottom_sheet) as? FrameLayout
        bottomSheet?.let {
            BottomSheetBehavior.from(it).state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
        }
    }
}

return dialog
```

Comment: Didn't work for me ;(

Comment: not working for me too.

Comment: No it does not, this just goes circles around the problem. Anyways, I haven't tested any of this since the question was posted, nor has it been fixed, the apis for handling softinput on Android is still horrendous. I have now moved to flutter as it solves a lot of the weird necessary UI issues while still letting me do stuff native as per the requirements. It even works with windows now which is great.